# Like look in a mirror

Tags: sentence-construction

1. We both know what it feels like looking in a mirror and not like what we see.
2. We both know what it feels like look in a mirror and not like what we're seeing.
3. We both know what it feels like looking in a mirror and not liking what we see.

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: Please don't post a sequence of sentences and ask which is correct.  You can get better answers by explaining why you think any of them might be right or wrong.  You can explain the context that you might want to use these sentences. You can describe what you have done already to answer the question.

Comment: (Inappropriate comment deleted) Mod reminder: please don't insult another user who has done nothing but try and help you write better questions. You should keep in mind that choosing the best sentence and finding errors are considered proofreading requests and are thus off-topic here on ELL. I have relaxed the rules and given such questions as yours the benefit of the doubt, because I believe new users will eventually learn to write good questions. But that doesn't mean questions like yours are up to snuff. You should start working on your question quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third answer is correct, "We both know what it feels like looking in a mirror and not liking what we see."

The first sentence should be "liking" instead of "like".

The second sentence could be revised to say "We both know what it feels like *to* look in a mirror and not like what we're seeing."